# Modelling realistic ground and blending with hdri background

Tags: modeling, texturing, hdri

Just after some advice as can't seem to find right tutorial.

So i've modeled a house and have a nice hdri background but can't really get the land/ground right. I've had this problem before.

Main issue - if you use a plane with texture you get the harsh edges where it "meets" the background hdri.

I know you can hide the edges using objects etc but doesn't work if you rotate camera etc.

Also, I'm just trying to create a grass ground but don't want to use particle system as I think that will be too heavy on render times. Is there a clever way of having realistic grass in foreground and then lower poly image in background of ground.

Essentially, what are the easiest way people make a good realistic ground terrain which is not too memory heavy....

Thanks